# how to get maximum and minimum salary group by designation and location

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data of two tables. In the first table I have employee id's and their names. In the second table, I have employee details (such as salary, location, join date, projects handled, designation).

I am trying to write a query where I can bring the data of maximum and minimum salary group by location and designation. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT E.EMPID,I.EMPID, E.EMPNAME, I.EMPNAME,
B.[MAXIMUM SALARY],F.[MINIMUM SALARY],
B.DESIG,F.DESIG,B.LOCATION,F.LOCATION
FROM
((SELECT MAX (SALARY) [MAXIMUM SALARY], LOCATION, DESIG
FROM
EMPDETAILS
GROUP BY LOCATION, DESIG) B
JOIN
(SELECT C.EMPID,C.SALARY,C.GENDER,C.DESIG,
C.JOINON,C.LOCATION,C.PROJECTS,D.EMPNAME 
FROM EMPDETAILS C
JOIN
EMPLOYEE D 
ON C.EMPID=D.EMPID) E
ON E.DESIG=B.DESIG AND E.SALARY=B.[MAXIMUM SALARY] AND E.LOCATION =             
B.LOCATION) 
FULL OUTER JOIN[enter image description here][1]
((SELECT MIN(SALARY) AS [MINIMUM SALARY], LOCATION, DESIG
FROM EMPDETAILS
GROUP BY LOCATION, DESIG) F
JOIN
(SELECT G.EMPID,H.EMPNAME,G.DESIG,G.GENDER,
G.JOINON,G.LOCATION,G.PROJECTS,G.SALARY
FROM EMPDETAILS G
JOIN EMPLOYEE H
ON G.EMPID=H.EMPID) I
ON I.DESIG=F.DESIG AND F.[MINIMUM SALARY]=I.SALARY AND     
I.LOCATION=F.LOCATION)
ON I.DESIG=E.DESIG
ORDER BY B.LOCATION, f.location
```

Giving me:

[image]

Comment: The query that you have won't give you what you show in the image. Moreover, Max and Min salaries are Grouped By location and designation. How would you associate an employee id with a group of records? That won't be true.

Comment: did you want your min/max salaries grouped by employeeID?

Comment: Hello. Actually I have two tables one for employee details which is in image, another one is for employee name. I want maximum and minimum salary to be displayed in each location (Bangalore, Hydrabad and kolkata) for each designation (Manager, Associate and team lead).

Comment: No I don't want it to group by employee id, I want it to group by location and designation. In kolkata location 6 rows will be grouped together, 2 rows will reflect maximum and minimum salaries of designation manager, next 2 rows will reflect maximum and minimum salaries of designation team lead and last 2 rows will reflect maximum and minimum salaries of designation associate. I was able to reflect either maximum or minimum salary of each designation group by location. But I am not able to combine the values of maximum and minimum salary of each of these designation group by location.

Comment: Do you see 6 rows for location Kolkata in the image you have? If the image is one of the tables then why would you write 'Giving me' on top of it? I guess first you'll need to learn how to post a question. Downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

no clue what you really want/need, but if you want employeeID-level results, you'll need something like:

```
SELECT 
    d.*,
    min_salary,
    max_salary
FROM 
    EMPDETAILS d JOIN
    EMPLOYEE e ON 
    d.EMPID=e.EMPID JOIN
    (SELECT
        empid,
        MIN(salary) AS min_salary,
        MAX(salary) AS max_salary
    FROM
        EMPDETAILS
    GROUP BY
        empid) m ON
    e.empid = m.empid
```

if you want min/max salaries grouped by LOCATION, DESIG as in your code, you'll need to return those results separately from employee-level details:

```
SELECT
    LOCATION, DESIG,
    MIN(salary) AS min_salary,
    MAX(salary) AS max_salary
FROM
    EMPDETAILS
GROUP BY
    LOCATION, DESIG
```

you don't need separate subqueries for your `min` and `max` groupings, you don't need to join your detail tables multiple times, and you don't need a `full outer join`.